# How to find collections by its nested object's objectId in Spring Data using repository interface?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that has items like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e4d31d1f6b66e5163962e3c"),
    "name" : "bob",
    "nestedObject" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("53f5a623cb5e4c1ed4f6ce67")
        //more fields...
    }
}
```

Java representation of this item looks following:

```
public class SomeObject {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private NestedObject nestedObject;

    //getters and setters
}
```

The Repository interface is defined like this:

```
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeObject, String> {
    public List<SomeObject> findByName(String name);
    public List<SomeObject> findByNestedObjectId(String id);
    //some other find functions
}
```

Now, `findByName(String name)` is working as it should be, but `findByNestedObjectId(String id)` returns nothing.

**Question is**: is it possible to find collection items by it's nested object's attribute using repository interface? If not, what is the recommended way to approach this problem? Is it possible without reimplementing whole repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Spring-data-mongodb` would not convert **_id** field to **ObjectId** type automatically in nested class on query operation. You should convert it manually. For example:

```
public List<SomeObject> findByNestedObjectId(String id) {
    Query query = Query.query(new Criteria("nestedObject._id", convertToObjectId(id)));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, SomeObject.class);
}

Object convertToObjectId(Object id) {
    if (id instanceof String && ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return new ObjectId(id);
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Eventually I ended up using different logic in my service handling this repository. In there I have a method `getByNestedObjectId` which is calling first `NestedObject no = nestedObjectRepo.findOne(id)`, and then `SomeObject result = someObjectRepo.findByNestedObject(no)`.

Comment: Would you not mind this will cut down executive efficiency by accessing database 2 times and the second time is a more complex query?

Comment: That's not correct. Nested ids should be converted automatically. Also for query executions.

Comment: @Oliver Gierke: I had the same experience as the questioner and if it's incorrect my code will just help nothing. But sorry that I made a mistake, now I know it has been upgraded on latter version. `The problem exists at version 1.0.4.`

Comment: 1.0.4 of what? If that's Spring Data MongoDB then ancient is probably the best way of describing that version :). The current version is 1.5.2.

Comment: `spring-data-mongodb-1.0.4.RELEASE`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using spring-data-mongodb:1.8.2.RELEASE  @OliverGierke can you please share solutions? Thx

Answer (score 28):

I've figured out how to solve this.

Change the parameter type to org.bson.types.ObjectId; from String

```
public List<SomeObject> findByNestedObjectId(ObjectId id);
```

and when you call it use

```
 repositoryName.findByNestedObjectId(new ObjectId(theIdString));
```

Comment: This worked for me using 1.8.2 version. findByNestdObjectId(String id);
Does not work, I had to use ObjectId and not string to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

If `NestedObject` looks like this:

```
class NestedObject {

  @Id String id;
}
```

and the `String` value you hand into the query is a valid `ObjectId` the query:

```
findByNestdObjectId(String id);
```

should work. If it doesn't feel free to create a ticket in out [JIRA](http://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO) and provide a tiny test case to reproduce it.

Comment: Having same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196033/spring-data-mongodb-unable-to-find-an-object-by-nested-documents-id  could you please take a look @OliverGierke ? Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on 1.6.2 spring-data-mongodb. But having issues with latest versions.

```
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeObject, String> {
    public List<SomeObject> findByName(String name);
    @Query("nestedObjectProperty._id : { $oid : ?0}")
    public List<SomeObject> findByNestedObjectId(String id);
    //some other find functions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nestedObject id needs to be converted into an

```
 org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

then the ObjectId can be used with repository method

```
findAllByNestedObject_Id(ObjectId)
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Can you provide working sample code to illustrate that. Please take a look at this guide "[answer]" to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the mongoDB query used by the repository with @Query. I'm not 100% the below query is excact but something along this:

```
public interface SomeObjectRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeObject, String> {
    public List<SomeObject> findByName(String name);
    @Query("{nestedObject._id : ?0}")
    public List<SomeObject> findByNestedObjectId(String id);
    //some other find functions
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it is working but not for `_id`. It is a good answer as long as you are querying the DB by anything other than _id. Id's are handled differently. Example in mongo shell: `db.somecollection.find({ 'nestedObject._id' : "magicId"})` is returning nothing, while `db.somecollection.find({ 'nestedObject._id' : ObjectId("magicId") })` is doing ok. I have tried to add `ObjectId(?0)` to `@Query` but then I got JSON parsing exception from java. Still, thanks for fast reply :)

Comment: Is it possible to add an "@Id nestedObjectId" or such to NestedObject? Then the query should definitely work using that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following for Spring-boot; works like charm for me:

```
@Query("nestedObjectProperty.$id : ?0")
```